# Calling java webservice from sharepoint 2010 event receiver

Tags: java, .net, web-services, sharepoint-2010

We are using sharepoint event reciever as given below:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           if (properties.ListItemId > 0 && properties.ListId != Guid.Empty)
           {
               string id, url, operation;
               url = properties.AfterUrl;
               operation = "Update";
               id = properties.ListItemId.ToString();
               //id=properties.ListId.ToString();
               JavaSendAlert.AlertWebServiceService jsa = new   JavaSendAlert.AlertWebServiceService();
               jsa.sendAlert(id,url,operation);
           }
```

JavaSendAlert is a WSDL consumed, made in java and published on a 32 bit systyem.

We get exception on this line:
**JavaSendAlert.AlertWebServiceService jsa = new   JavaSendAlert.AlertWebServiceService();**

The Exception is:

> Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe" /noconfig
>   /fullpaths
>   @"C:\Users\461167\AppData\Local\Temp\OICE_FEF98CDC-FC33-4071-B497-DC6B21E9E725.0\w1tuwwu5.cmdline"

What we can do with this exception.

---

Thanks for replying

the error on the page u shared is not sma eas mine.

my error path is C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\OICE_FEF98CDC-FC33-4071-B497-DC6B21E9E725.0\w1tuwwu5.cmdline

and on the page u shared is  @"D:\WINNT\TEMP\eyrpuhyg.cmdline and is quite common in internet.

I am still not able to solve the problem but, people faced the same problem while installing SQL server  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/480562d9-d5db-4ce6-848a-a334c40dc3b9

Thanks
Mohit Leekha

Answer (score 0):

with this information i can only guess... i'd say it's a permission/authentication issue - check out [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315904) KB.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked

i just changed the trust level to farm which was previously set to sandbox.

Thanks
 Mohit Leekha